# creating a new clean branch in Git for a v2 rewrite

Tags: git, branch, branching-and-merging

I'm getting ready to start version 2.0 of a library, a complete rewrite. I'll basically start from scratch, but I'd like to keep working within the same Git repository. I'm trying to figure out how to approach creating a clean new brach for the rewrite.

The naive way to start would be to create a new branch, and delete everything:

```
$ git checkout -b v2
Switched to a new branch 'v2'

$ rm -rf *
$ git commit -m "empty the branch for a clean slate"
$ git push origin v2
```

However, it's not ideal to have this commit that deletes everything in the branch. I'd like to be able to create a new empty branch, while keeping the commit history.

It seems like `git checkout --orphan v2` will create a new empty branch, but it also has no parent.

Is there another way to create a clean empty branch without losing commit history?

Comment: Could you create a branch of of the master branch's initial commit (`git branch master <sha1-of-very-first-commit>`)? Of course, it won't share the history of `master`, and I'm not sure if that's what you mean by "without losing commit history", but it would be in the same tree at least.

Comment: interesting idea! thanks! in general, this would work, but having that history is useful. I'll have to think on this for a bit...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your history will always be in the v1 branch. Ie master. When v2 becomes stable you can make that master and rename the old master to v1

Orphan is the best way way to start fresh

Comment: does merging an orphan branch back into master work as expected (as in any other branch)?

Comment: No. You wouldnt want to merge if the new one was truely a re write. Merging finds a common base which an orphan commit will not have

Comment: good to know. thanks! this is why I'm hesitant to use `--orphan`. I'll basically have to create a new master branch and a new develop branch to live alongside the existing. not ideal, but probably best.

Comment: I don't understand. If you need to rewrite then use an orphan. If you can roll v1 forwards then do that.